# Databricks SQL no valid syntax for SET OWNER TO

Tags: sql, databricks

I am trying to execute a change of table ownership in databricks SQL editor.

I have tried several iterations, all of which are receiving a syntax error:

```
ALTER TABLE <table_name> SET OWNER TO <owner_name>; 
ALTER TABLE <table_name> OWNER TO <owner_name>; 
ALTER TABLE <table_name> SET OWNER <owner_name>; 
ALTER TABLE <table_name> OWNER = <owner_name>;
```

Comment: According to this, the second syntax is correct. Specifically what error do you get? Do you have Unity Catalog enabled? https://docs.databricks.com/en/_extras/notebooks/source/set-owners-notebook.html

Comment: Yes, Unity catalog is enabled. The second syntax returns: [PARSE_SYNTAX_ERROR] Syntax error at or near 'OWNER'.line 1, pos 87

Comment: Figured it out - you have to wrap the owner in backticks - this is not documented

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct syntax must wrap the owner in backticks:

```
ALTER TABLE <table_name> SET OWNER TO `<owner_name>`;
```